# What happens if a calculation within a Timer Tick, takes longer than the Tick length?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

In a C# `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, what would happen if the code within the timer tick took longer to calculate than the tick length?

For example, in the code below, what would happen if updating the label took longer than the interval of the tick (1 second)?

```
private void timerProgress_Tick( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        if( label.Value <= label.Maximum )
        {
            label.Value = item;
        }
        update_label();
    }
```

I can't seem to find any answers for this, though it seems like an obvious question.

Comment: are you asking if it would spawn multiple processes?

Comment: Have you tried experimenting to see what happens?

Comment: "discovery requires experimentation"

Comment: If you're performing long-running tasks here, you're using it wrong. This timer's `Tick` events are forced onto the UI thread, and you shouldn't be blocking that thread.

Comment: I'm just trying to see what it would do, no idea if it would spawn multiple processes or not. I have tried experimenting but it doesn't seem to do anything unusual (just carries on as it should), does that mean it doesn't complete the calculation and just goes to the next tick? @JonSkeet

Comment: My process is a short one that is as simple as updating a number on a timer, but I was curious as to what would happen if you were to exceed the `Tick ` time. @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: My answer (which I deleted) was for System.Threading.Timers... Winforms one will (if I remember correctly) just queue the tick events (essentially blocking your UI thread if *all* tick events take longer than the interval). Not posting as answer since I'm not 100% sure, but it should take just a few minutes to make a simple project and test it.

Comment: Once the Tick event handler method finishes, it will immediately fire again.  Your user interface will become very sluggish since it can only respond to input when the Tick event handler isn't executing.  The main thread of your program will burn 100% core.  All very easy to notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments for the question, the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` will queue the `Tick` events, blocking the UI thread if *all* `Tick` events take longer than the set interval.

The event will continue to calculate for as long as it needs, regardless of the interval time.

For example, if you were to make a countdown timer with a tick of one second, but have it contain calculations that take 1.3 seconds, it would be delayed. This means your count down time will be incorrect as a 30 second count down will actually last around 39 seconds, regardless of the one second `Tick` length.

Of course, long-running tasks should not be completed within a `Timer` event, as these are forced onto the UI thread, and you shouldn't be blocking that thread.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Windows.Forms.Timer` will fire on the UI thread only (the thread that the owning form is bound to), and will fire at some time after the time period has elapsed, when the thread is otherwise idle (including repainting the window). The event handler blocks the thread from doing anything else (including handling user input and repaint events) until it has returned.

To avoid an unresponsive UI, you should typically use this timer only for animations. You could queue a task to the thread pool, but you might as well use `System.Threading.Timer`, which fires its events on the thread pool. Note, however, that `System.Threading.Timer` does *not* check that the previous event handler has returned.

Under the covers, `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` is based on the Win32 `SetTimer` API.